# Why there is no E_NOTICE error in the first call?

Tags: php

I have a following code snippet:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    function &getVal() {
       $data = [];

       return $data['hey'];
       //return $whatever; 
    }

    function getVal2() {
       $data = [];

       return $data['hey'];
    }

    var_dump(getVal());  // No E_NOTICE error is issued - why?
    var_dump(getVal2()); // E_NOTICE error is issued.
```

And the question is: Why there is no `E_NOTICE` error in the first call? The explanation is most likely that the variable `$data['hey']` is created to return a reference. However, it still seems wrong not to issue an E_NOTICE error when `$data['hey']` (or `$whatever`, `...`) is not defined.

Comment: You answered the question yourself. As to "seems wrong"... this is PHP, right?

Comment: Well, you are absolutely correct. Problem is, it instantiated it by the mere action of referencing it. It probably has to do with how references are handles under the hood, as for instance calling a `preg_match('..','..',$match);` would of course also not complain about `$match` not existing yet, as the point is filling it. See the _return by reference_ as 'I want you to access _and alter_ data at this location'. That you immediately discard that variable after the return as the scope closes is beside the point. I'm not saying it's very pretty, but it is how it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behaviour

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign

> If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it
>   will get created.

And some related "bugs":

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30350

> Ok, it appears that the element is created because we are attempting
>   to return a reference to something that does not exist.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27627

> When you try to access a non-existant array element you  effectively
>   create it, hence the NULL entries in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to reference and its weaknesses in PHP.

When you reference in PHP the binding is created. PHP object typing is not strict and php doesn't know what kind of object is referenced that is interpreter assumes that `['hey']` may exists in object.

PHP lacks of late binding and strict typing. That is why such "weird" things sometimes occur.

Answer (score -3):

Use only `error_reporting(1)`
 at the top of the php file...

Comment: This is a very terse answer. More explanation would be helpful.